# Python list in list

Tags: python, list

I want convert list as follow:

```
list=[['a','b','c','d'],'e','f']
```

to

```
list['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

how could I do this....Helples..

Comment: What output do you expect for `[{1,2}, (3,4), '56', {7:8}, 9]`?

Comment: If you knew it was always going to take that particular shape, you could say:

    `list = list[0] + list[1:]`

By the way, I know you're using `list` as an example name, but keep in mind that it's a built in function used to construct lists, so you shouldn't ever actually use that as a name.

Comment: It is not particular shape,I still cannot figure out how to convert it....

Answer (score 0):

Check out `itertools.chain`, I think it's exactly what you need: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain

---

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> li = [['e', 'f', 'g'], 'a', 'b']
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(li))
['e', 'f', 'g', 'a', 'b']
```

This is pretty much the example from the documentation of that function, which is always a good place to start...

Comment: I still cannot figure out how to do it..